# Make red color for wrong prediction in python plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn

I am trying to make scatter plot based on my ML project.
I am able to plot actual and prediction to compare the results.
I found that there are some wrong prediction. I would like to add wrong prediction with different color and `label = wrong prediction` in my plot if it exists.

This is my csv file :

```
actual    prediction       a           fz      |f|             x           y        z  
Type A   Type A     -0.000     -7.73E-0   0.0787842      0.196073     0.787512     0.0199747
Type A   Type A     -6.778     -0.90804   1.0700144      -0.684156    -0.434421   0.325416
Type A   Type B     -9.819     -1.31495   1.31,-0.1      0.179948     0.176147    0.0199747
Type A   Type A     0.0009     3.22E-05   5.655          0.0963595    0.543199    0.524067
Type B   Type B     -4.869     -0.65256   0.9908314      0.067153     0.01946     2.13765
Type A   Type A     -2.011     -0.26955   0.2714327      0.510215     -0.0682776  0.238572
Type A   Type A     0.4791     0.064248   0.2755128      -0.130218    0.320991    1.79398
Type A   Type A     -38.76     -5.19988   6.6145229      -0.0181393   0.0299295   0.294921
Type B   Type B     -0.478     -0.06421   0.0688118      -0.0351119   -0.368596   2.84933
Type A   Type A     2.5160     0.337279   0.4894226      0.768108     0.0176798   0.164874
Type B   Type A     -2.826     -1.27761   1.4760467      0.415485     0.430448    2.24944
```

This is my code which plots only actual and prediction

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('./actual_prediction.csv')
print(df.columns)


def scatter_plot_real(df):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
    
    sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="a", hue="prediction", data=df_actual, 
                   palette=['dodgerblue','green'], legend='full')
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.show()

print(scatter_plot_real(df))
```

I need an idea to make `red` color for wrong prediction (`if 'type' != 'prediction'`) with label in the same plot.
Is it possible?

I hope I made my question clear.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an first make a `correct` column which tells if the prediction for that index was true or not and then use the `hue` parameter for this column.

```
df["correct"] = (df["actual"] == df["prediction"])

plt.figure(figsize = (20,5))
sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = "x", y = "a", hue = "correct", palette=['red','blue'], legend='full')
plt.show()
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: @Codeholic Lemme know if it worked!

Comment: This idea works for false and true prediction. I was wondering if it is possible to plot false, Type A and Type B in the same plot. Thanks